# SPA won't loads in 4G but loads in Wifi

Tags: ssl, wifi, lets-encrypt, 4g

I have an application (writen in React.js) that works perfectly in Chrome Browser on my computer.

When I try to load the app on my phone with Chrome, the app loads well when I am in Wifi but not when I am in my mobile network (4G).

I have a perfectly valid SSL certificate created with Let's Encrypt.

Do you have an idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use google chrome dev tool with 3G etc...

Please see the article : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: Yes, I have no informations. It says that "No security details are available for this origin.". I have an ERR_TIMED_OUT error. When i activate my Wifi connection, it works.

If I share my 4G connection and connect with my computer in Wifi to my 4G mobile data it also works.

That's no sense

Comment: The IPv6 of my server had changed. I upated my DNS AAAA record and it works now.